# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat not working for time without leading zero

Tags: php

I am using DateTime::createFromFormat, its working fine for time with leading zero. But not working for time without leading zero.

For ex.
12/15/2014 -- 15:4:2
My code

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y G:i:s', $temptime);
```

Comment: Why are you using minutes/seconds without leading 0? Looks odd, and probably why it's not working. Doesn't even look like there is a spec for minutes without leading 0s. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: i am parsing a time from a webpage which use time without leading zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a date construct [spec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) which recognizes no leading 0 for minute/seconds. If you are parsing bad timestamps from a remote site, you will have to sanitize programatically, akin to:

```
$myTimestamp = echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('--', '', $remoteTimestamp)));
```