# DateTime::createFromFormat doesn't recognise hours without leading zeros

Tags: php, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494913/php-datetimecreatefromformat-not-working-for-time-without-leading-zero) to this one, but it concerns only minutes and seconds. My question is about hours. Let's assume that we want to parse time in the following format: 63000, **6** = hours, **30** = minutes, **00** = seconds. I think we should do it like this:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Gis", "63000");
```

**G** = 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros, **i** = minutes with leading zeros, **s** = seconds, with leading zeros

Unfortunately it doesn't work in PHP 7.0.12. The function returns false.   If I change the first argument to: "G:i:s" and the second argument to "6:30:00", it returns a correct DateTime object. Am I misunderstanding something here, or is it a bug?

Comment: It is possible that this is a bug. You could work around it by modifying your format. It should be trivial to add a leading 0 to the string if it is required. Similar to the accepted answer in the question you link to.

Comment: @vascowhite yep, that's what I did. I just wanted to know whether I'm using this function in a wrong way, or if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Yep, ran into the same problem, although, already figured out that `sprintf('%06d', $time)` would help, although, need to make edge case check if initial format is `Gis` and change it to `His`

Comment: I think that actually may be a bug. Did you report it to the PHP team?